# How to annotate that a function produces a dataclass?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, python-typing

Say you want to wrap the `dataclass` decorator like so:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

def something_else(klass):
    return klass

def my_dataclass(klass):
    return something_else(dataclass(klass))
```

How should `my_dataclass` and/or `something_else` be annotated to indicate that the return type is a dataclass?
See the following example on how the builtin `@dataclass` works but a custom `@my_dataclass` does not:

```py
@dataclass
class TestA:
    a: int
    b: str

TestA(0, "") # fine


@my_dataclass
class TestB:
    a: int
    b: str

TestB(0, "") # error: Too many arguments for "TestB" (from mypy)
```

Comment: `dataclass` **is not a type**. There is no such annotation because it wouldn't really make sense

Comment: This seems to be related to an ongoing issue with mypy: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/708

Comment: But yeah, I believe the dataclass decorator syntax is special-cased. So, trying to extend it naturally isn't going to work. But it may be worth bringing up an issue in the mypy github

Comment: There's nothing particularly special about a class that has been processed by `dataclass`. I can't think why you would worry about it from a static-typing perspective. It's not really important, for example, whether `__init__` was defined manually or autogenerated by the decorator. (Put another way, `dataclass` is basically a way to prepare the name space for the eventual call to the metaclass, not a feature of the resulting type itself.)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Well, not all "type" annotations refer to types - Iterable, Generator, Callable. They encompass types that match a certain pattern/protocol. Dataclasses are very common, so having annotations to work with them seems pretty reasonable to me.

Comment: @chepner "I can't think why you would worry about it from a static-typing perspective." - because in this example, we lose all information about it being a dataclass, which means there is no `__init__` from a static-typing perspective.

Comment: There's no such thing as "a dataclass", only classes that were constructed *using* the `dataclass` constructor. Such classes have an `__init__` method; it's just constructed by the decorator rather than you writing it explicitly. In what situation do you imagine that difference matters at runtime?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the issue - this has nothing to do with runtime. This is about whether you can tell your linter that the class is a dataclass, i.e. whether it defines the methods/properties that a dataclass is expected to define. In the example, the linter recognizes the implicit `__init__(self)` signature, but it should be `__init__(self, a: int, b: str)` as defined by the dataclass.

Comment: "Well, not all "type" annotations refer to types - Iterable, Generator, Callable." No, these *are* types. What they aren't are *concrete classes* in the sense of things that can be instantiated. But like all types they describe a category of classes/values. In that regard, ``dataclass`` *isn't* a type but instead it is a function; one that is special cased by type checkers to understand what it does.

Comment: If we're being honest I don't understand why the question is being upvoted. I don't agree with the original intent behind it and i'm curious about those who *are* interested in identifying that a class is a dataclass. As in I am legitimately interested in learning their use cases and in what scenario this would end up mattering exactly.

Comment: @rv.kvetch ``dataclasses`` also codifies a system for working with such types, such as ``fields``, ``asdict``, ``replace``. Some things that are extremely complicated in the general case are absolutely trivial with ``dataclasses``; restricting utilities to work on them can immensely simplify the scope.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no feasible way to do this prior to [PEP 681](https://peps.python.org/pep-0681/).

A `dataclass` does not describe a type but a transformation. The actual effects of this cannot be expressed by Python's type system – `@dataclass` is handled by a [MyPy Plugin](https://github.com/python/mypy/blob/e0f16ed027ff7bcd30d9a4dffebe95c101447b8d/mypy/plugins/dataclasses.py) which inspects the code, not just the types. This is [triggered on specific decorators](https://github.com/python/mypy/blob/e0f16ed027ff7bcd30d9a4dffebe95c101447b8d/mypy/plugins/dataclasses.py#L24-L27) without understanding their implementation.

```py
dataclass_makers: Final = {
    'dataclass',
    'dataclasses.dataclass',
}
```

While it is possible to provide custom MyPy plugins, this is generally out of scope for most projects. PEP 681 (Python 3.11) adds a generic "this decorator behaves like `@dataclass`"-marker that can be used for all transformers from annotations to fields.

PEP 681 is available to earlier Python versions via [`typing_extensions`](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/).

##### Enforcing dataclasses

For a pure typing alternative, define your custom decorator to *take* a dataclass and modify it. A dataclass can be identified by its `__dataclass_fields__` field.

```py
from typing import Protocol, Any, TypeVar, Type
import dataclasses

class DataClass(Protocol):
    __dataclass_fields__: dict[str, Any]

DC = TypeVar("DC", bound=DataClass)

def my_dataclass(klass: Type[DC]) -> Type[DC]:
    ...
```

This allows the type checker to understand *and verify* that a `dataclass` class is needed.

```py
@my_dataclass
@dataclass
class TestB:
    a: int
    b: str

TestB(0, "")  # note: Revealed type is "so_test.TestB"

@my_dataclass
class TestC:  # error: Value of type variable "DC" of "my_dataclass" cannot be "TestC"
    a: int
    b: str
```

##### Custom dataclass-like decorators

The PEP 681 `dataclass_transform` decorator is a marker for *other* decorators to show that they act "like" `@dataclass`. In order to match the behaviour of `@dataclass`, one has to use `field_specifiers`  to indicate that fields are denoted the same way.

```py
from typing import dataclass_transform, TypeVar, Type
import dataclasses

T = TypeVar("T")

@dataclass_transform(
    field_specifiers=(dataclasses.Field, dataclasses.field),
)
def my_dataclass(klass: Type[T]) -> Type[T]:
    return something_else(dataclasses.dataclass(klass))
```

It is possible for the custom dataclass decorator to take all keywords as `@dataclass`. `dataclass_transform` can be used to mark their respective defaults, even when not accepted as keywords by the decorator itself.

Comment: This seems to be the best alternative at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that mypy understands the `metaclass decorator` and its magic
about `__init__`, but does not understand the `dataclass function`:

```
@dataclass
class Test:
    a: int


# Mypy: Revealed type is "def (self: Test, a: builtins.int)"
reveal_type(Test.__init__)


class Test2:
    a: int

#Mypy: Revealed type is "def (self: builtins.object)"
reveal_type(dataclass(Test2).__init__)
```

As you can see, the `__init__` method of `Test2` does not accept any arguments.